# How to debug GWT application in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-maven-plugin

How to debug GWT application in Eclipse?

I am developing maven project with gwt-maven-plugin.
My application consist of one page with one button for sending request to the server. It is assumed that clicking the button starts the handler on the server.
When i try to debug code in Eclipse, all breakpoints in target method not work.

Comment: What do you want to debug? Client code or server code?

Comment: @ElHoss I want to debug client code and server code

Comment: client code should be debugged using the browser & server code in Eclipse. Having a multi module, it is quite simple. Maybe a good point to start: https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k